# ¿Qué función hace esto en la clase polinomio?

Tags: c++, poo

tengo una clase para crear un objeto que forme un polinomio de cualquier grado.

Y la clase con su parte privada sería así según el ejemplo que estoy intentando tratar de comprender:

```
class polinomio
{
public:
//...
private:
  double* coeficiente;
  unsigned gradoMax;
  unsigned grado;
};
```

Por tanto entiendo que:

```
unsigned gradoMax;
```

se encarga de guardar el grado máximo del polinomio.

```
unsigned grado;
```

si no me equivoco es el grado actual que tenga un coeficiente en un momento determinado. Por ejemplo si el polinomio es de grado 3 y yo quiero consultar qué coeficiente tiene en el grado 2 pues este atributo tendrá como valor grado 2.

Creo que coeficiente es un vector de coeficientes en el que según su posición en el vector así corresponderá al término independiente(grado 0), coeficiente del grado 1 (posición 1 del vector) pero en realidad ahí se declara un puntero pero... ¿a qué? Ésto es lo que no logro entender:

```
double* coeficiente
```

¿Qué hace ese puntero? ¿A dónde apunta? ¿Voy bien encaminado según lo que he expuesto anteriormente para lograr tener un objeto polinomio?

Muchas gracias.

### ACLARACIÓN/AMPLIACIÓN

Ya he logrado conocer en qué consiste cada cosa:

```
double *coeficiente;
```

Es un puntero que apunta a un vector dinámico con los coeficientes, en la posición i del vector guardará el grado i.

```
unsigned gradoMax;
```

Es el grado máximo que se puede almacenar.

```
unsigned grado;
```

Es el grado del polinomio almacenado. Es el valor más alto del índice en el vector coeficiente.

Por tanto para no abrir otra pregunta sigo con la duda, si tu creas dentro de una clase un puntero como en el caso de `double *coeficiente;` ¿Dónde se crea el vector dinámico? Eso no lo llego a entender.

Gracias nuevamente.

Comment: Si el programador puso un nombre acorde al uso, entonces ... puede que **si** tengas razón, o **puede que no**, dependerá del uso que le de a esas variables. Si el programador usó nombre que le parecieron bonitos ... pues **puede que si** o **puede que no**, dependiendo de tu grado de clarividencia.

Comment: Dicho lo anterior, voto por cerrarla como `basada en opiniones`.

Comment: @Trauma acabo de actualizar la pregunta, lo que no logro ahora saber es cómo un puntero como miembro de una clase puede crear un vector dinámico. ¿No se debería de crear el vector dinámico o es que con crear un puntero ya ese puntero almacenará en las posiciones de memorias correlativas las variables? Gracias a todos.

Comment: A ver: ¿ De verdad esperas que, sin ver el código, alguien pueda saber **al 100% de seguridad** para que es y como se usa cada variable ? Salvo que sea el propio creador, claro está. Si es un puntero, en alguna parte del código se usará, bien para reservar memoria, bien para apuntar a un dato procedente de otro sitio. Busca llamadas a `new`, `malloc` o `calloc` para ver donde se reserva la memoria (si es que se reserva y no se usa para otra cosa).

Comment: @Trauma yo personalmente no veía mi pregunta como opinión, pero bueno no obstante, gracias por ayudar en lo posible compi :)

Comment: Efectivamente, está basada en **adivinaciones**, no en opiniones. Sigo sin entender como esperas que alguien *acierte* en el uso de una variable **solo por su nombre**. Y, tal y como te comenté anteriormente, para saber donde la reserva, seguro que tu editor tiene la entrada de menú `buscar`. Y, a diferencia nuestra, el **si dispone del código** :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preguntaba sobretodo qué era el puntero:

```
double* coeficiente;
```

Y una vez he podido con ayuda de @carlosezam junto con algunos libros y un ratillo lo he logrado comprender.

`double* coeficiente` es un puntero que almacenará la dirección de memoria de un vector (vector que se define en su constructor).

Cuando uso un constructor así:

```
polinomio::polinomio(unsigned gradoMax)
{
  coef = new double[gradoMax];
  grado_ = 0;

  for(int i=0; i<=gradoMax; i++)
  {
    coef[i] = 0.0;
  }
}
```

Lo que se hace es que `coef = new double[gradoMax];` (el puntero declarado en la clase) le digo que a partir de esa dirección de memoria almacene `gradoMax` espacios de memoria consecutivos.

Por tanto, **ahí justo es donde se crea el vector que guardará cada coeficiente** en dichas posiciones consecutivas según el tamaño declarado en la variable gradoMax.

¡Gracias a todos como siempre por vuestra ayuda! :)

Comment: Entonces califica la respuesta del que te ayudo o la tuya misma para indicar esto como resuelto

Comment: Ya está hecho @element Un saludo!

Answer (score 2):

normalmente en el constructor. Sería algo como esto:

```
coeficiente = new double[ MAX_COEFICIENTES ];
```

donde `MAX_COEFICIENTES` seria un numero asignado por ti o una constante que indique el tamaño del arreglo.

La implementación del constructor debería verse algo así:

```
polinomio::polinomio()
{
    // 20 es solo un ejemplo, pero creo que es un numero considerablemente grande
    // si se trata de numero de coeficientes de un polinomio.

    coeficiente = new double[ 20 ];

    // Luego seguiría el resto del código...
}
```

al final se debe liberar la memoria asignada dinamicamente en el destrcutor de la clase, así:

```
polinomio::~polinomio()
{
    // evitamos fugas de memoria
    delete[] coeficiente;
}
```

Comment: Aventurarte a decir cómo, porqué y para qué se usa una variable, basándote solo **en su nombre y su tipo**, me parece poco realista e incluso un *pelín* pretencioso O_O

Comment: No aseguré nada. Solo estoy dando ejemplos de como se asigna memoria dinámica NORMALMENTE en C++. "La implementación del constructor DEBERÍA verse así".

Comment: Y llegamos al punto exacto: **no lo podemos saber** porque la pregunta no incluye el código. Dicho de otra manera, no has respondido a esta pregunta.

Comment: Eso de *normalmente en el constructor...* no lo veo del todo claro. ¿No podría ser también, *normalmente*, una lista enlazada? ¿O un contenedor de la STL?

Comment: "¿No se debería de crear el vector dinámico o es que con crear un puntero ya ese puntero almacenará en las posiciones de memorias correlativas las variables?" eso es lo que está preguntando el compañero. Y yo le di un ejemplo de como se asigna la memoria dinámica, obviamente hay infinidad de manera de hacerlo. Puede ser al estilo C con malloc, al estilo c++ con New, con un contenedor de la stl o con un contenedor de boost, etc.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias @carlosezam Efectivamente por ahí iban "los tiros" y de ahí era mi pregunta, entre lo que me comentaste y lo que he sacado por mí ya lo he logrado comprender, ahora actualizo con mi respuesta. Gracias compañero :)